# Android IllegalArgumentException: The tag for fragment_XXX is invalid. Received: layout-sw600dp/fragment_XXX_0

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I am currently trying to configure the layouts of my app to support multiple screen sizes.
This process needs a lots of testing by my side, so I continuously keep deleting/moving/refactoring layout files.

However, at the moment i cannot resolve the exception as written in the title because it is being shown every time i run my app. Before this exception i had another layout folder called **layout-land** and then just deleted this folder and moved its content to the **layout-sw600dp** folder.

I 've tried multiple ways to solve this issue:

1. I deleted all the extra layout-(s)w* folders
2. Did a restart of Android Studio and invalidated caches
3. Project clean/rebuild several times

Is there anything else that it would help me?

**EDIT**

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The tag for fragment_XXX is invalid. Received: layout-sw600dp/fragment_XXX_0
>    at com.example.myapp.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:422)
>    at androidx.databinding.MergedDataBinderMapper.getDataBinder(MergedDataBinderMapper.java:79)
>    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
>    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:130)
>    at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.inflateInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:1409)
>    at com.example.myapp.databinding.FragmentXXXBinding.inflate(FragmentLoginBinding.java:146)
>    at com.example.myapp.databinding.FragmentXXXBinding.inflate(FragmentLoginBinding.java:132)
>    at com.example.myapp.XXXFragment.onCreateView(LoginFragment.java:74)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
>    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
>    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
>    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
>    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
>    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
> ```

Comment: Post the stack trace. It may be helpful. Also, why are you deleting/moving/refactoring layout files to test multiple layout files?

Comment: Posted the stacktrace, see the below the 'EDIT' in the main post. I 'm doing that because i might want some layouts to be supported in smaller or bigger screens. So there is case where initially i would have created a layout for screens with shorter width 600dp and then i decided to use that layout in even smaller screens that 600dp.

Comment: The error is in data binding and it looks like you are doing all the right things regarding how to recover from the error. In my experience, data binding can get into an odd state at times. Sometimes, rebooting my computer has resolved data binding issues but I can't say why. You could try invalidating caches, shutting down AS, then manually deleting all the build files directly as well as deleting the .idea file in your project's root before restarting AS.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your answers @Cheticamp! Secondly, i am still not able to find a solution to my problem. I also did i what i read in [this](https://medium.com/back-market-engineering/put-your-android-studio-on-a-diet-fa4d364acb05) article!

Comment: If you've done all that then the problem is probably in your code. I would dig in there next. Perhaps set a break point on the code that is calling the exception to get an idea about what is going on.

Comment: I don't think that i have an error in my code regarding that. For instance, i have checked that the _sw600dp view xml_ is enclosed between **<layout/>** tags or that the *same view ids* are being used. Even i deleted all the extra layout folder and i kept only the default one and then i cleaned my project, removed .gradle, .idea directories, invalidated cache and all this stuff suggested to resolve this error and still not able to run my app properly. I might try to use another version of the Android Studio and checkout my project in a new directory in my pc.

Comment: I meant your Java/Kotlin code not the layout XML. Try to track down where in your code the error is occurring. It could be as simple as identifying the wrong layout for a binding (however that may happen) or something similar that may become obvious to you once you look for the root cause in your own Java/Kotlin code. Good luck!

Comment: Finally i am able to build my project properly, after doing everything mentioned in the above comments. I don't know for sure if there is any error in my source code, however i know that in case i move a layout to another swXXXdp directory, the same error will occur again. It would be nice to know why this happens, or how to resolve this issue instead of attempting to find a way out by guessing.

Answer (score 3):

Set the view to 'Packages' by clicking the dropdown icon on the top-left side of Android Studio. It will list all the layout directories created. Delete the layout-sw600dp dir and any other directory you don't need. Clean and rebuild your project. The error will disappear.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In my case, even though I Invalidated cached files and restarted android studio, I still would have got the same error. What worked for me was I searched `layout-sw600dp` in the root of my file directory, and 2 JSON files containing that phrase popped up. I deleted those, and after that, everything worked just fine.
I hope it helps you too.